# Error with setInterval()

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I'm creating a stopwatch with setInterval like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Stopwatch</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Saira" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="stopwatch.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="but">
        <h1>Stopwatch</h1>
            <p id="timer">0</p>
            <button id="start">Start/Stop</button>
            <button id="reset">Reset</button>
            <button id="record">Record Time</button>
        </div>
    <script src="stopwatch.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the JavaScript file:

```
var timer = document.getElementById("timer");
var sec = 0;
var on = false;
var interval;
//execution
document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", startStop);
//function
function startStop(){
    if(on == false){
        counter();
        on = true;
    }else if(on == true){
        clearInterval(interval);
        on = false;
    }
}

function counter(){
    interval = setInterval(time, 1000);
}

function time(){
    sec += 0.01;
    timer.innerHTML = sec;
}
```

I set the interval at 1000 to test it. It worked well at the first 5 seconds, but at the 6th second, the number shown was 0.060000000000000005, and the 9th, 10th, 11th didn't work as well. Can anybody help me fix this problem please?

Comment: Are you referring to the number at the end after all the 0s?

Comment: `timer.innerHTML = sec.toFixed(2)`?

Comment: What I don't understand is why I set the sec to += 0.01 but the result was like that.

Comment: @NewbieCoder Read the duplicate post. Long story short, it's because floating point representations aren't capable of storing every possible number, so some rounding happens. It can't store `0.06`, but it can store `0.060000000000000005`.

Comment: Thank you. I thought it was the error in the setInterval(). Now I understand why.